# Network disconnected over and over again

Tags: networking, 15.04, disconnect

Network keeps on disconnecting after 2 to 3 mins on Ubuntu 15 gnome and every time I have to run `sudo service network-manager restart` to get it working again

Comment: check whether Power Management is on using iwconfig

Comment: I checked it using iwconfig . It's off.